# Check mark a table row containing selected option

Tags: jquery

I have a table with many rows, I would like that if i select a value in the select box in a given row, the checkbox in that row is checked and if the select box is having an empty value/no value the checkbox in that row is also unchecked.

My work so far

```
 $('#the_worksheettable  .selectbox_1').change(function(){
            value =$(this).val();
            if(value !==''){
               $('.checkbox_1').prop('checked',true); 
            }else{
              $('.checkbox_1').prop('checked',false);    
            }
        }); 



<table class="tg" id="the_worksheettable">
            <tr>
                <th class="tg-031e">ID</th>
                <th class="tg-031e">TEST NAME</th>
                <th class="tg-031e">TEST NAME / MOLECULE</th>
                 <th class="tg-031e">SELECTOR</th>
            </tr>
            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                    <td class="tg-031e">1</td>
                    <td class="tg-ugh9">Capsule with Acid and buffer</td>
                    <td><select name="molecule[]" id="" class="selectbox_1"> 
                                    <option value="">-Select-</option>
                                   <option value="Uniformity">Uniformity</option>
                                    <option value="Relative Density">Relative Density</option>
                                     <option value="Trimethoprim">Trimethoprim</option>

                        </select></td>
                    <td class="tg-031e"><input type="checkbox" value="Capsule_with_Acid_and_buffer"name="test_names[]" class="checkbox_1"/></td>

                </tr>
                                <tr>
                    <td class="tg-031e">1</td>
                    <td class="tg-ugh9">Capsule with Acid and buffer</td>
                    <td><select name="molecule[]" id="" class="selectbox_1"> 
                                    <option value="">-Select-</option>
                                   <option value="Uniformity">Uniformity</option>
                                    <option value="Relative Density">Relative Density</option>
                                     <option value="Sulfamethoxazole">Sulfamethoxazole</option>

                        </select></td>
                    <td class="tg-031e"><input type="checkbox" value="Capsule_with_Acid_and_buffer"name="test_names[]" class="checkbox_1"/></td>

                </tr>
                                <tr>
                    <td class="tg-031e">2</td>
                    <td class="tg-ugh9">Uniformity of Weight</td>
                    <td><select name="molecule[]" id="" class="selectbox_1"> 
                                    <option value="">-Select-</option>
                                   <option value="Uniformity">Uniformity</option>
                                    <option value="Relative Density">Relative Density</option>
                                     <option value="Trimethoprim">Trimethoprim</option>

                        </select></td>
                    <td class="tg-031e"><input type="checkbox" value="Uniformity_of_Weight"name="test_names[]" class="checkbox_1"/></td>

                </tr>
                                <tr>
                    <td class="tg-031e">2</td>
                    <td class="tg-ugh9">Uniformity of Weight</td>
                    <td><select name="molecule[]" id="" class="selectbox_1"> 
                                    <option value="">-Select-</option>
                                   <option value="Uniformity">Uniformity</option>
                                    <option value="Relative Density">Relative Density</option>
                                     <option value="Sulfamethoxazole">Sulfamethoxazole</option>

                        </select></td>
                    <td class="tg-031e"><input type="checkbox" value="Uniformity_of_Weight"name="test_names[]" class="checkbox_1"/></td>

                </tr>
```

Comment: would be great if you can share the html as well.

Comment: (Just a sample row will do.)

Comment: just to be sure i am reading this correctly, if you click on any cell in a row then you want the check box to be toggled?

Comment: "... if i select a value in the select box in a given row..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to only target the checkbox in the same tr where current select lies:

```
$('#the_worksheettable  .selectbox_1').change(function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.checkbox_1').prop('checked', $(this).val()!=="");
});
```

**### Working Demo**

Comment: Good answer but i must ask, why add the ? true:false
this is a bool value:  $(this).val()!==""

Answer (score 3):

Below should do the trick

```
$('#the_worksheettable  .selectbox_1').change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    if(value !== ''){
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.checkbox_1').prop('checked',true); 
    }else{
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.checkbox_1').prop('checked',false);    
    }
});
```

Comment: this is not going to work as select will lie inside td element. `.parent('tr')` will return no object. here is the demo https://jsfiddle.net/zLwnu006/

Comment: @MilindAnantwar Right. Changed it. Remembered wrong, forgot `.parent()` only goes 1 level up.